# Return User's id from mysql table with autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, autocomplete

Simply I want to handle `id` column's value seperately to use it in a hidden field for mySQL. But when I fetch n`ame,surname,id` they are appearing in search text field also `id` value appearing. *I only want to use id in hidden field's value area.* And only Name, Surname must appear in text field. How can I set id's value to hidden field instantly?

[image]

**autocomplete.php**

```php
<?php 
include 'config/db.connect.php';
$return_arr = array();


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,user_username,name,surname FROM user WHERE name LIKE :receiver or surname LIKE :receiver or user_username LIKE :receiver');
    $stmt->execute(array('receiver' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
         $return_arr['name'] = $row['name'];
         $return_arr['surname']= $row['surname'];
         $return_arr['id']= $row['id'];
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);

 }

?>
```

**script in my form's page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//autocomplete
$("#receiver").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete.php",
    minLength: 1,

    select: function(event, ui) { 
    $("#receiver_id").val(ui.item.value); 
}

});             

});
</script>
```

**FORM**

```
<form action="action_send_message.php" method="POST"  >
     <label for="receiver">Receiver</label>
     <input type="text" name="receiver" id="receiver" placeholder="Receiver" class="span12" />
     <input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" id="receiver_id" value=""/>
     <textarea id="messagebody" name="message_body" class="wysihtml5 span12" rows="5" placeholder="Mesajınızı Yazın"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large color-10">Gönder</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of `SELECT id,user_username,name,surname`, just `SELECT user_username, name, surname`?

Comment: Or if you do want the ID but prefer it to be hidden, why isn't your `<input type="hidden">` working?

Comment: autibyte, removing the id from the select isn't going to work, as the OP stated that they needed to use it in a hidden field.

Comment: @autibyte if I delete id from SQL query I can't return an ID value then how I can write ID to SQL table? I want to see user's ID only in hidden field's value area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITTED**

I suggest updating your code into something like the following:

**autocomplete.php**

```
....
     $return_arr[] = array('value' => $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'],
                           'id' =>  $row['id']);
....

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

**script in my form's page**

```
$("#receiver").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, data) { 
        $("#receiver_id").val(data.item.id); 
    }
});
```

Take note that the autocomplete output will only work when the array key on `$return_arr` items are `'value'`. If this was named something else, it will not work.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working. After autocomplete, I pressed Submit button with post method and I tried to get it with echo $_POST['receiver_id']; but it is showing noting

Comment: I updated my code and still it is not working :( now also it can not search anything

Comment: How bout changing `source: 'autocomplete.php'` to:

`    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
`

Comment: I updated the code above instead. Looks like a mess on the comment.

Answer (score 1):

this is an easier way to do it

search.php

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

           $return_arr[] = array('value' => $row['name'], 'id' => $row['id']);

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }



    echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

> 

```
$(function() {
>                 //autocomplete
>                 $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
>                     source: "search.php",
>                     minLength: 1,
>                     select: function(event, data) {
>                     $("#hidden").val(data.item.id);
>                     $("#autocomplete").val(data.item.value);
>                     },
>                 });
>             });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only returning the last result in a one-dimensional array to return the JSON object.
Your object would look like this:

```
{
    name: "Firstname",
    surname: "Surname",
    id: "id"
}
```

Instead of an array of results:

```
{
    "0": { name: "Firstname", surname: "Surname", id: "id" },
    "1": { name: "Firstname", surname: "Surname", id: "id" },
    "2": { name: "Firstname", surname: "Surname", id: "id" },
}
```

You're only seeing one result instead of several. jQueryUI defaults by assuming they're all one array of id-value pairs, so it assumes items with "Firstname" as a value with an ID of "name", and so on.
What you wanna do is:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $i++
     $return_arr[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
     $return_arr[$i]['surname']= $row['surname'];
     $return_arr[$i]['id']= $row['id'];
}
```

Instead of the while loop you're using in your code.
Then, autocomplete will hide the ID as the default behavior should do (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: How does your array of results look in the PHP results (try a search term manually)?